# How do I Store and read PublicKey from data base? I am using postgresql and java

Tags: java, database, postgresql, public-key-encryption, public-key

Hi I need to store and read public keys from a postgresql data base and i am using java.

I have this code to store

```
 cbd.ejecutarSeguro("update persona set llave_publica = ? where cedula = 112345678", x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());


    public void ejecutarSeguro(String query, byte[] pkBytes) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(nombreConexion);
            PreparedStatement pstat;

            pstat = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstat.setBytes(1, pkBytes);
            pstat.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

To read i use this

```
String filePublicKey_s = cbd.consultarArray("Select llave_publica from persona where cedula = 112345678").get(0).get(0);
        byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
        //encodedPublicKey = (filePublicKey_s).substring(2).getBytes();
        System.out.println("Public Key; "+filePublicKey_s);
        System.out.println("rescato de la base; "+(filePublicKey_s).getBytes());// LA que rescato de la base
        fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
        System.out.println("Public Key; "+encodedPublicKey);
        fis.close();
```

In example I have the public key in a file in my computer... when I compare the output I see this

```
Public Key: 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
Public Key; \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
From data base; [B@6a162595
From file; [B@53fd8f9
```

If I read the PK from the database i read an \x and all the PK change

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Convert the PublicKey into byte array

```
    byte[] bytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

write the bytes to a BLOB or BINARY column

```
...              
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update tbl1 set col1=?");
ps.setBytes(1, bytes);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

read it back to a  byte array

```
...
byte[] bytes = resultSet.getBytes(1);
```

convert bytes back to PublicKey

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(alg);
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
PublicKey pk = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store in Blob, you can read the public key file and get java public key object. You can directly store this publickey object in database as blob. First do :

```
 byte [] bytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

then store bytes in database.
For retrieving public key do as:

```
public PublicKey blobToPublicKey(final byte[] blob) 
    {
        Object result = null;
        final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
        ObjectInputStream ois;
        try
        {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            result = ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
           //
        }
        catch (final ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
           //
        }
        return (PublicKey)result;
    }
```